# Existence of a vector orthogonal to $\mathbf{1}$ and positive dot product with an arbitrary vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the vector of $1$'s. My question is whether the following is true and how to disprove or prove it: For any non-constant $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $w^\top \mathbf{1} = 0$ and $w^\top v > 0$.

We can assume $n \geq 2$. Note that I am interested in a strict inequality $w^\top v >0$. Otherwise, if we want $w$ such that $w^\top v \geq 0$, we could just choose $w$ orthogonal to $\mathbf{1}$ and $v$ (if $n \geq 2$), I guess.

Comment: What does it mean that a vector $v\in \mathbb R^n$ is non-constant?

Comment: @Desperado My guess is that the OP meant non-zero.

Comment: @Desperado It means that the entries of $v$ are not all equal. That is, $v$ is not a multiple of $\mathbf 1$

Comment: Yes, I mean that $v$ is not a multiple of $\mathbf{1}$.

Comment: @GEdgar I don't know how to do that to be honest. But I feel like that it must be possible always.

Comment: @GEdgar I think, I understood your point. Correct me if I am wrong. There always exists $x$ and $w$ as described in your comment. Then, we have $v = c \mathbf{1} + w$ and so $w^\top v = w^\top (c\mathbf{1} + w) = w^\top w > 0$?

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks! You can put it in an answer to the question and I will accept it if you want. But anyways, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, recall: We can write $v$ as a sum $v = x+w$ where $x$ is parallel to $\mathbf1$ and $w$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf1$.  (This is called "orthogonal projection". Also, it is the "Gram-Schmidt process" for just two vectors, $\{\mathbf1, v\}$.)  Since we are given that $v$ is not parallel to $\mathbf1$, we have $v \ne x$ so that $w \ne 0$.

Compute $w^\top v = w^\top(x+w) = w^\top x+ w^\top w = w^\top w > 0$.